# Shifting through concatenation in SystemVerilog?

Tags: system-verilog

I have the following question

Implement a circuit which shifts a 32-bit vector by two to the left and fills empty spots with zeros. Use only concatenation operator.

I'm just learning SystemVerilog, and I can't understand how I can use a concatenation operator for this. I would have just done 'assign y = a << 2' without concatenation ( with a declared as 32bit vector and y a 32 bit output), but I don't understand how can concatenation have anything to do with it.

Comment: `<<` has overflow that a synthesizer and linter should flag a warning for. Concatenation, if done correctly, will not. There is more than one way to get the same result. Your assignment is to do it a specific way. Study concatenation and find the equivalent to `a << 2`

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation allows you to concatenate multiple parts of a vector with constants. As such, the left shift operator for `a << 2` can be implemented as the following:

```
logic [7:0] x, y;
always_comb
   y[7:0] = {a[5:0], 2'b0};
```

Just a concatenation of the lower 6 bits of a with 2 bits of 0 on the right hand side. Same what the left shift would do, but without any overflow.